# Como adicionar as informações de referência no Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Em algumas oportunidades vendo alguns colegas usando o VS 2017, e até mesmo quando eu usei um configurado por outra pessoa, notei que existem informações sobre as referências a uma classe.

No exemplo abaixo, veja como está hoje:

```
public class Email
{
    public string EnderecoEmail { get; set; }
}
```

E abaixo, como eu gostaria que ficasse:

```
0 references
public class Email
    {
        0 references
        public string EnderecoEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

Como configuro para que meu VS exiba esse tipo de informação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tools → Options → Text Editor → All Languages → CodeLens
```

ou

```
Ferramentas → Opções → Editor de Texto → Todos os Idiomas → CodeLens
```

**O CodeLens não está disponível na Community Edition.** Porém no Visual Studio 2015 pode ser instalado o CodeLens ao instalar o [SSDT](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017).

Referência:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796941/visual-studio-2017-display-method-references